# eclipse deletes access rules after maven->update project

Tags: eclipse, maven

Eclipse (Mars 1) restricts the access to JavaFX classes, so I added 
an accessible rule for javafx/**.
That's fine until I do "Maven -> Update Project...". This deletes the access rule
every time.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should not mess up with Eclipse access rules but install [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) instead.

This plugin integrates with Eclipse and allows to develop JavaFX applications easily.